# How to create a collectionview with 3 cells on every row in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to create a collectionview with 3 items on every row in objective c. Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return items.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    
    NSString* buf = items[indexPath.row];
    
    CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    [cell loadCell:buf];
    
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIColor *leftColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = ((screenBounds.size.width)*0.25)/2;
    cell.layer.borderColor = leftColor.CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat boxWidth;
        boxWidth =  ((screenBounds.size.width)*0.25);
        bottomSpacing = 17;
    
    return CGSizeMake(boxWidth, boxWidth);
}
```

It look like the left but I want it to look like the right image.
[image]

What am I doing wrong and is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100); // or whatever the size you want
CGFloat minimumHorizontalSpacing = 10;
CGFloat minimumVerticalSpacing = 10;
CGFloat numberOfColumns = 3;

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    
    CGFloat fullWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat itemsWidth = (numberOfColumns * itemSize.width);
    CGFloat horizontalSpacing = ((numberOfColumns - 1) * minimumHorizontalSpacing);
    CGFloat itemsTotalWidth = (itemsWidth + horizontalSpacing);
    
    CGFloat horizontalInset = ((fullWidth - itemsTotalWidth) / 2);
    CGFloat verticalInset = 20;
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(verticalInset, horizontalInset, verticalInset, horizontalInset)
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return itemSize; 
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return minimumHorizontalSpacing;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return minimumVerticalSpacing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To represent 3 columns with collectionview, each cell has to be width of 1/3 of the display. (Since 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1)

So try the code below, I have changed the width of the cell:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat boxWidth;
        boxWidth =  ((screenBounds.size.width)/3.0); //Change made here
        bottomSpacing = 17;
    
    return CGSizeMake(boxWidth, boxWidth);
}
```

Comment: It works, but the buttons gets to big and there are no spacing between them. I want the size to be the same as the image buttons.

Comment: In Ios development, you have to manually calculate margins, padding, and spacing. If you want the buttons to be smaller, you could adjust the width by percentage or hard value. If you want to add more spacing to your cell, you could refer to minimumInteritemSpacing and minimumLineSpacing. What exactly do you want to do? Let me help you.